# How to implement fluid design to fit 1024x768 size monitor or higher?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

Simply, I want the body of the site to occupy 100% of the browser in 1024x768 monitors, and for monitors with higher resolution (1024x768 and higher) to display the body in the middle (center aligned) leaving equal amounts of space on the left and right.

This is very common in many websites but I don't know how to implement it. Can anybody show me how, please, and finish up the CSS code I started? Thank you very much.

HTML

```
   <div class="header">content</div>
   <div class="side-bar">content</div>
   <div class="container">content</div>
```

CSS

```
       html body{ 
       margin:0;
       background:#fff;      
       }
      .container{float:left}
      .side-bar{float:left}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Today, most visitors are using a screen resolution higher than 1024x768 pixels" - http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

so if you need to have a 1024 pixels width website you just make your container to be 1024 pixels fat :) and margin:auto;

http://jsfiddle.net/kx2nE/3/

I used a smaller size one so you can see better the result in jsfiddle, but you can replace those values in your css.

```
#container
{
  width:300px !important;
  height:500px !important;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:auto;
}

<div id="container">
    container with equal margins on window resize<br />
    <br /><br /><br />

    <b>
    width and height values set to yours 1024x768
    </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Fluid 960 Grid System - http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

It lets you nicely organize content divs in a horizontal grid that takes up 100% of the browser's width.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this type of question is not encouraged on stack overflow due to the fact that you didnt actually present a problem. However there is a very good css coder who has solved this for you. Here is a link the download for you to try.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-1-column-full-page-pixels.htm

Answer (score 0):

Set width to a percentage and min-width for fixed size on 1024 monitors:

```
#main {
width: 95%;
min-width: 990px; /* I suggest a number around 990, due to scroll bar width, experiment at will or use javascript to apply dynamically */
```

To align the site centered, use an automatic horizontal margin:

```
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: You need to apply these to a div directly beneath the body (The body itself cannot change size)

```
<body>
<div id=main>
<div class="header">content</div>
<div class="side-bar">content</div>
<div class="container">content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Edit: Ah I see what you mean, fluid with maximum width, most of the aforementioned stands, change 95% to 100% and min to max:

```
#main {
width: 100%;
max-width: 990px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: fixed width in % will not work I think, cause switching on a bigger screen the website will get 95% width of that screen. It will not go under 990px but for sure it can be bigger. That's only my ideas, I could be wrong.

Comment: That's what he wanted right? Hence "Fluid"... If not just change `min-width` to `width` and you're done. Edit: Other way round I see...

Comment: oh, I might get it wrong, but I think he, or she wants it to be 1024px/768px for 1024x768 monitors (meaning fullscreen) and for biger screens the site have to be also 1024x768 but centered in the window with equal margins in left and right part. That's how I see it.

Comment: Yeah I got it backward, well the answer is there now, the concept works for any layout system you want really, most people want it the other way round that's all.

Comment: "the concept works for any layout system you want really" - tottaly agree with you.